# Efficiently Set Up Reference Table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have two 300MB base files on the network and several reference tables, which only use one or two columns from the base files.  The first step of a reference table is to bring in the source table (all columns) and then the second step is to remove all the unneeded columns.  However, this is extremely inefficient, and every time I do a data refresh after altering my table queries, it takes 5-10 minutes for every reference table to load the entire datasets.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this which would lead to faster load times?  I am assuming that instead of the reference tables I could have a new table which selects only the one or two columns needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create your BaseTable and import the source (all Columns), name it "BaseTable"
Now create a new query (blank) and type = BaseTable. On enter you can now remove the columns you do not need. On all other tables you repeat this. So your source is only imported and you get the columns you need from this source without repeating the imoporting of your source data.

Comment: You are welcome, please confirm by accepting the answer.